# Should I use Route 53 subdomain or domain with Elastic Beanstalk and Blue Green Deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have a Java EB application deployed to environment accessible via this url:

```
app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

I have registered this domain name:

```
jthinkws.com
```

and I will have to deploy a new version and keep the existing one

```
v2.app2.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

and then would want to swap url to swap to new environment.

And I may want to release another separate completely application within another subdomain within domain.

```
app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

So my point is that the domain jthinkws.com is only going to be used by AWS, but I would want to use it to match to multiple eb instances as follows

Start With

```
app1.jthinkws.com     ----> app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Go to

```
app1.jthinkws.com     ----> v2.app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
app1old.jthinkws.com  ----> app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

and then

```
  app1.jthinkws.com     ----> v2.app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
    app1old.jthinkws.com  ----> app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
    app2.jthinkws.com     ----> app2.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

So Im unclear whether I follow the instructions in Route 53 for domains or subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working fir the first EB environment, basically get a new domain just for use by amazon and then setup CNAME records for each subdomain, then wait takes a while for changes to go through.

- Registered Domain Name jthinkws.com (with fasthosts)
- Created new trusted Zone in Route 53 for jthinkws.com
- Update Name servers in fasthosts to point to nameservers listed as recordset in Route53
- Added new record Set for jthinkws.com
      Name :app1.jthinkws.com
      Type :CName
      Value:app1.jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
- Wait for two days

Similar process for other subdomains, instead of a CNAME record you can also create an A record of type ALIAS to the environments load balancer instead and that also works. Im unclear of the advantages/disadvantages of both approaches.